# SQL multiple table join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
A
---------
a_pk | id

B
----------------------
b_pk | id | link | foo

C
----------------------
c_pk | id | link | bar
```

All records in `B` have a matching record in `A`; all records in `C` have a matching record in `A`, but records in `B` and `C` do not necessarily have to match each other.  I want to get the set of results where A has a match in either B or C.  Individually, the queries would be:

```
SELECT A.id, B.foo FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
SELECT A.id, C.bar FROM A INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id
SELECT B.foo, C.bar FROM B FULL JOIN C ON B.id = C.id AND B.link = C.link
```

What would I need to fill in to make this work?

```
SELECT A.id, B.foo, C.bar FROM <join A, B, C>
```

I'm using Oracle if it makes a difference, and I would prefer to avoid using a subquery if possible.

**[edit - for clarification]**

I want *only* the records from `A` that have a match in either `B` or `C`.

Comment: if you want to Join 3 tables, you just need 2 joins, not 3

Comment: I am aware of that, I put 3 queries to show the relationships between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a left join.  (I'm not very familiar with Oracle but I assume this should work.)

```
SELECT A.id, B.foo, C.bar
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C on A.id = C.id
WHERE B.id IS NOT NULL OR C.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: No, that would give me records where A does not have matches with B or C.

Comment: The `WHERE` condition given filters out all records in A that do not have matches in either B or C.